# Using Intents to pass data for ringtones

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, ringtone

So far I've been making applications with set as Ringtone feature by creating 1 activity for 1 file. It was bad because with apps with more than 20 ringtones I would've needed 20 activities which would affect app size and performance. Then I found that there is a way to do that with only 1 activity and layout, passing data with Intents. Now I have pretty good idea how that works except one thing that bothers me. That is how do I define strings.
I need 1 string for name and 1 for file path

My code:

```
Boolean success = false;
                    rsound = new File(rpath, "Slow tone.mp3");rpath.mkdirs(); //Copied file name
                    if (!rsound.exists()) {




                        try {
                            InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.s8slowtone); //path for file 
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(rsound.getPath());
                            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                            int read = 0;

                            try {
                                while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                                    out.write(buff, 0, read);
                                }
                            } finally {
                                in.close();

                                out.close();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            success = false;

                        }
                    } else {
                        success = true;
                        setRingtone();

                    }

                    if (!success) { 
                       setRingtone();


                    }
                }

                private void setRingtone() {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, rsound.getAbsolutePath());
                       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Slow tone"); //Ringtone name
                       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
                       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, " ");
                       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
                       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
                       values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

                       Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(rsound.getAbsolutePath());
                       getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + rsound.getAbsolutePath() + "\"",
                               null);
                       Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

                       RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                               S15.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                               newUri);
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ringtone set successfully",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

So How do I do this? How do I define string for each file and how to pass them?

Since question is unclear for some members I will make it simpler
I don't have idea how should I write strings so when I start RingtoneManager Activity using Intent, I pass data from strings.
So How should I write my code to pass this

File name "Slow tone.mp3"

File path: R.raw.s8slowtone)

Ringtone name "Slow tone"

Comment: I don't understand what you need, it's the code of the activity which set the ringtone right? You want to get file name and name from intent?

Comment: I want to know how should I write strings so I can pass them when I start new activity.

Comment: "how should I write strings" => Can you be more specific? You create string using " "

Comment: How should I make strings so when I pass it it has path, file name and ringtone name.

Comment: In this case you don't "create" a `String` you get it from somewhere.. resources? Where your ringtone are stored?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I've done a lot today, figured how to send data using intents, there is only one thing thats bothering me. I sent strings for Ringtone name and created File name, to send Path I need `int` 
   `  final  String C1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("PATH").trim();` this doesn't work because  I get error: The method openRawResource(int) in the type Resources is not applicable for the arguments (String)

@ `InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.s8slowtone); //path for file 
`

Comment: then pass it as integer, do putExtra("PATH", integer); then path = .getIntExtra("PATH", 0);... check if (path != 0) openRawResource(path);

Comment: Did my last comment fixed your problem?

Comment: Um not really, It quite different, it should be: `int res = R.raw.s14projectil;
          intent.putExtra("PATH", res);`
I got it working tho, not sure what to do about Bounty

Comment: Not really I mean: you should save it in an array of int where you have all ringtones and then pass it based on position

Comment: I will post an answer when i can about how to launch an activity pass the selected ringtone to it and set it in the activity that's is what you need?

Comment: I figured it out. It's working. No need for an answer anymore.

Comment: Then post an answer with the solution and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Intent f27=new Intent(context, RMpro.class);
         if (f27 != null){
         f27.putExtra("FileName", "Horn!"); //Copied file name
         int res = R.raw.s28horn; // Path to File in App ressources
         f27.putExtra("FilePath", res); //Passing path with intent
         f27.putExtra("RingName", "Horn.mp3"); // Ring name
         ((Activity)context).startActivity(f27);
         }
```

And then in Ringtone Manager, in my case `RMpro`

```
 final int FPATH=i.getExtras().getInt("FilePath");
       final  String RNAME = getIntent().getStringExtra("RingName").trim();
       final  String FNAME = getIntent().getStringExtra("FileName").trim();
```

And then just:

```
rsound = new File(rpath, FNAME);rpath.mkdirs();

InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(FPATH);

values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, RNAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

To call your activity, just place this function anywhere, and call it with your desired parameters. It will build an intent and fill in the parameters:

```
 public static void runRingToneActivity(Context context, String ringToneName, String ringTonePath, String ringToneFilename) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(context, RingToneActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("NAME", ringToneName);
    intent.putExtra("PATH", ringTonePath);
    intent.putExtra("FILE", ringToneFileName);
    ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent);
}
```

Inside your `RingToneActivity's` onCreate, you just retrieve the parameters you just passed:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           . 
           .


    Intent intent=this.getIntent();

    String ringtoneName=intent.getStringExtra("NAME");
    String ringtonePath=intent.getStringExtra("PATH");
    String ringtoneFile=intent.getStringExtra("FILE");

            // you have them, now use them!

}
```

NOTES:

- Substitute "RingToneActivity.class" in the function for the name of your activity, if it is different.

Comment: I tried with your code and It gave me so many illogical errors
`Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
  LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
 - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
 - Syntax error on token ",", ; expected`

Comment: the "." means there's more stuff in your activity xDD

Answer (score 0):

You can pass entire objects via intent. You just need to implement Serializable interface for the class you want to pass. Example:

```
public class Ringtone implements Serializable
{
    public String name;
    public String path; //can be integer
    public String file;
}
```

send via intent:

```
Ringtone ringtoneObj = new Ringtone();
intent.putExtra("test",ringtoneObj);
```

retrieve via intent:

```
Ringtone ringtoneFromIntent = (Ringtone) intent.getSerializableExtra("test");
```